# How can I check a date between range where it is not in use?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I write a renting software but I dont get any further...

I have a table like this:

```
car_id
date_from
date_to
```

When anyone want to rent with this dates:

```
DATE_FROM: 2023-09-09
DATE_TO: 2023-09-15
```

Now I have to check all dates in my database where these dates are not in use.

```
SELECT 

car_id,
date_from,
date_to

FROM cars

INNER JOIN (
 SELECT date_from, date_to FROM booking WHERE (DATE_FROM NOT between date_from AND date_to) AND (DATE_TO NOT BETWEEN date_from AND date_to 
)
```

idk what I am doing wrong. I hope anyone can help me to solve this issue

thank you very much!!

Comment: Have you tried ```WHERE NOT (DATE_FROM between...)```?

Comment: What I can see is you have two tables Cars and Booking. Does the Booking has Car_id column? why i am asking is because you can have bookings of different car_id so by justing checking available dates won't solve the problem.

Comment: @ArbindChandra car_id is a foreign key from table cars, yes there a different car id, I also check where car_id = $car_id but I did not wrote this in the code

Comment: so what i understand is that you will get DATE_FROM and DATE_TO from user input and then will search if any car is available or not, correct me if i am wrong.
In this case, why don't you write your query something like this.

SELECT 
C.car_id,
DATE_FROM AS date_to,
DATE_TO AS date_to
FROM cars C
LEFT JOIN booking B ON C.car_id = B.car_id
WHERE DATE_FROM NOT between date_from AND date_to AND DATE_TO NOT BETWEEN date_from AND date_to OR B.car_id IS NULL

Comment: I don't understand why the `date_from` and `date_to` is stored in the `car` table. That should be in the `booking` table (which in turn has a foreign key to the `car` table).

Comment: I am unable to paste the complete sql here, so just pasted in answer, pls see this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you may deploy the [`datarange` data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) for the booking interval.

The table would have a following DDL

```
create table booking 
(car_id int,
 booking_range daterange
)
```

and your sample parameter range would you write `'[2023-09-09, 2023-09-15]'::daterange`

Note that the *square brackets* indicate that both end are *inclusive*, parenthesis `)` is *exclusive*.

With the following sample data

```
insert into booking(car_id, booking_range)
values
(2, '[2022-10-01, 2022-10-10]'::daterange),
(2, '[2023-10-01, 2023-10-10]'::daterange),
(3, '[2023-09-10, 2023-09-20]'::daterange),
(4, '[2023-09-11, 2023-09-12]'::daterange),
(5, '[2023-08-10, 2023-09-10]'::daterange)
```

you can use the *overlap* operator `&&` to identify the bookings that *overlap with your range*.

```
select * from booking 
where '[2023-09-09, 2023-09-15]'::daterange && booking_range
;

car_id|booking_range          |
------+-----------------------+
     3|[2023-09-10,2023-09-21)|
     4|[2023-09-11,2023-09-13)|
     5|[2023-08-10,2023-09-11)|
```

The query you are about is to get all cars *that have no booking that overlaps with the parameter  range*  - use simple `not in` with the above subquery:

```
select * from car
where car_id not in 
(
  select car_id from booking 
  where '[2023-09-09, 2023-09-15]'::daterange && booking_range
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I created a daterange field and want to update the booking_range but I got this error: error: malformed range literal

Comment: const a = await connectors['xxx'].query(`
    UPDATE booking SET booking_range = $1::daterange;
  `, [[new Date(2023, 1, 1), new Date(2023, 1, 5)]]);

Comment: The correct range literal is `'[2023-01-01, 2023-01-05]'::daterange`  @newexe91

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to realise that two intervals (s1,e1), (s2, e2) overlap when (s1 < e2) and (s2 < e1).

The following select gives you all the available car for a given interval (in the example `01/07/2023` - `01/27/2023`

```sql
select id as car_id,
'01/07/2023' as date_from,
'01/27/2023' as date_to
from car c
where c.id not in (
    select car_id
    from booking
    where date_from < '01/27/2023'
    and date_to > '01/07/2023'
)
```

For this schema an test data

```sql
create table car (
   id integer
);

create table booking(
    car_id integer,
    date_from timestamp, 
    date_to timestamp
);

insert into car values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6)
;

insert into booking values
    (1, '01/01/2023', '01/10/2023'),
    (1, '01/20/2023', '01/30/2023'),
    (2, '01/05/2023', '01/08/2023'),
    (3, '01/23/2023', '01/29/2023'),
    (4, '01/15/2023', '01/16/2023'),
    (5, '01/01/2023', '01/03/2023'),
    (5, '01/28/2023', '01/30/2023')
;
```

The result is

| car_id | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 01/07/2023 | 01/27/2023 |
| 6 | 01/07/2023 | 01/27/2023 |

[Play with it on DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oKCeauxLqBWqzoHH7AK7Xd/0)

You might have to replace < and > with <= and >= depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I got this error: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "booking"

Comment: SELECT 
      cars.id,

      booking.car_id,
      booking.date_from,
      booking.date_to

      FROM cars

      WHERE cars.id NOT IN (
        select booking.car_id from booking where booking.date_from <= $1
        AND booking.date_to > $2
      ) AND cars.id = $3;

Comment: You can't reference `booking` since you are selecting rows where no booking row exists for.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand the problem statement is to get the availability based on certain date as an input parameter. So this query will work.

```
DECLARE @cars TABLE (car_id int);
DECLARE @Booking TABLE (car_id int, date_from DATE,date_to DATE);

INSERT INTO @cars(car_id)
VALUES('2'),('1');

INSERT INTO @Booking
(
car_id,
date_from,
date_to
)
VALUES
(   1, '2023-01-11',  '2023-01-15'),
(   1, '2023-01-05',  '2023-01-08'),
(   2, '2023-01-12',  '2023-01-14')

-- Now if you want to check the availiblity from 12th Jan to 13th Jan
DECLARE @DATE_FROM DATE = '2023-01-12'
DECLARE @DATE_TO DATE = '2023-01-13'

SELECT 
C.car_id,
@DATE_FROM AS date_to,
@DATE_TO AS date_to
FROM @cars C
LEFT JOIN @booking B ON C.car_id = B.car_id
WHERE @DATE_FROM NOT between date_from AND date_to AND @DATE_TO NOT 
BETWEEN date_from AND date_to OR B.car_id IS NULL
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help and comment. All Works fine! But there is one thing. in date_from I have to check also the time. So when the date_from 2023-01-01 09:00:00 its available but 2023-01-01 09:00:01 its not available so I have to say also when the time is also exact like 09:00:00 only in date_from how can I make it

Comment: @newexe91 in that case you will get datetime as in input parameter and you can cast the datetime to Date only for the To_date comparison. something like CAST(@DATE_TO AS DATE) NOT 
BETWEEN date_from AND date_to OR B.car_id IS NULL